# How to search data within object using elasticsearch 7+ java API

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to search all the documents where role_id is 8 and status.id is 5. I have below index for my data.

I have tried to get data only by role_id is 8  with below query

```
{
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "filter": [
          {  "match" : {"role.role_id" : 8} }

        ]
      }
    }
}
```

It returns **"hits": []** not sure what is wrong here.

I am new to elastic search and I have seen many documents where they mentioned **nested** type for objects. Is this mandatory? do I need to change the index?

```
{
    "contacts": {
        "aliases": {},
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                 "roles": {
                    "properties": {
                        "role_id": {
                            "type": "long"
                        },
                        "role_name": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "status": {
                            "properties": {
                                "id": {
                                    "type": "text",
                                    "fields": {
                                        "keyword": {
                                            "type": "keyword",
                                            "ignore_above": 256
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "name": {
                                    "type": "text",
                                    "fields": {
                                        "keyword": {
                                            "type": "keyword",
                                            "ignore_above": 256
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/contacts/_search?q=roles.role_id:8%20AND%20roles.status.id:5'
```